Import an ONNX model in sympy or MathML
Is there a way to import an ONNX model in sympy or MathML?
I want to re-use my machine learning models across different frameworks. One of them is not directly compatible with ONNX, but can use sympy or MathML.
So far I have not found a direct importer/exporter, and could also not find a way to export to sympy/MathML from one of the free-to-use ONXX-compatible tools.
I checked the websites of these tools, e.g. pytorch, for export to sympy/MathML, and the sympy repository for importers but I only found converters that worked the wrong way round, i.e. importing a sympy model into a ML framework.
